# New to error handling

Tags: powershell

The path that I have set is not valid, when the copy fails I want to send an email to someone. If there is no error then send an email stating the copy was successful. 
Current it doesnt give me an error and it doesnt send an email. I know that the email part is correct and confirmed it does work.

My script block.

```
try
{
 Copy-Item -path "\\main-
 4\info\SmartPlant\app\CitrixRelease\domain\app\*" -Destination "\\domain.com\citrix\Installation Media\app\" -force -ErrorAction Stop
 }
catch
 {
 $from = "alerts@domain.com"
 $to = "me@domain.com"
 $subject = "Copy Failed"
 $body = "The Copy failed to complete, please make sure the servers rebooted"
 $msg = "$file"
 $Attachment = "$file"

 $msg = new-object Net.Mail.MailMessage  
 $smtp = new-object Net.Mail.SmtpClient("mail.domain.com")  
 $msg.From = $From 
 $msg.To.Add($To)
 if($Attachment.Length -gt 1)
 {
    $msg.Attachments.Add($Attachment)
 }
 $msg.Subject = $Subject 
 $msg.IsBodyHtml = $true  
 $msg.Body = $Body 
 $smtp.Send($msg)
 }
```

Comment: Right now you would only send the mail in case an exception is raised. Would your current copy command raised an exception?

Comment: I wrote a blog post on try..catch that might help you: http://wragg.io/powershell-try-catch/

Comment: Right I think I have what you have. Just not sure whats wrong.

Comment: I removed the stop at the end of the error action and it now works.

Comment: Strange, I would have thought you'd need to use `-erroraction stop` or the error might be non-terminating. Still if it works, it works.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How about this as a solution for sending an email for both failure and success without duplicating the email send code:

```
$Status = 'Succeeded'
try{
    Copy-Item -path "\\main-4\info\SmartPlant\app\CitrixRelease\domain\app\*" -Destination "\\domain.com\citrix\Installation Media\app\" -force -ErrorAction Stop
}catch{
    $Status = 'Failed'
}finally{
    $from = "alerts@domain.com"
    $to = "me@domain.com"
    $subject = "Copy $Status"
    $body = "The Copy $Status"
    If ($Status = 'Failed') {$body += ", please make sure the server is rebooted" }

    $Attachment = "$file"
    $msg = new-object Net.Mail.MailMessage  
    $smtp = new-object Net.Mail.SmtpClient("mail.domain.com")  

    $msg.From = $From 
    $msg.To.Add($To)

    if($Attachment.Length -gt 1){
        $msg.Attachments.Add($Attachment)
    }

    $msg.Subject = $Subject 
    $msg.IsBodyHtml = $true  
    $msg.Body = $Body 
    $smtp.Send($msg)
}
```

You don't really need to use a `Finally` block, but it does create a nice code block to make explicit what the email functionality belongs to.